# What is the most efficient way to calculate PI in C?

Tags: c++, c, math, pi

I'm have to write a C program, what it does is takes a integer as input. And gives output to the input(th) number of PI after decimal. Like if input is 100, output will be 9(100th digit of pi, after decimal is 9). 
What will be the best algorithm for that?

p.s I don't want to save the value of pi into the string, and do it.

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: efficient for what? memory? time?... [Mysticial](http://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) is the current world record holder for most digits computed and have a few programs to calculate it

Answer (score 4):

Your question is more a math question than a C programming one (so perhaps off-topic). Read first the wikipage on [Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) and [Approximations of π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80)

If you need to compute only a few hundred (or even hundred thousands) digits, you just need to use some algorithm and code it using some [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library (e.g. [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org), which has [mpfr_const_pî](http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Special-Functions) ass commented by [chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870253/chtz)).

Things become interesting for many billions of digits. I'm not expert on Pi, but look into [Fabrice Bellard work](https://bellard.org/pi/pi2700e9/) on it (read the [technical notes](https://bellard.org/pi/pi2700e9/pipcrecord.pdf) mentioning [Chudnovsky's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm)).

Comment: You may also want to look at the [**Chudnovsky algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm)

Comment: Which is the one used by F.Bellard

Comment: Learn something new every day. I'd seen the 22.4 trillion digit run by Peter Trueb, but didn't click to Bellard. Thanks.

Comment: If you already suggest using GMPlib, why not directly use [`mpfr_const_pi`](http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Special-Functions) from MPFR?

Comment: Because I don't know enough GMPlib to be aware of that.

Comment: Another good one [Computing Pi in C to 800 digits in a 160 byte C program](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/pi/code.html) -- It's pretty slick.